# unable to install .deb apps with gdebi

Tags: applications, apps

in Files, I am unable to install .deb apps with gdebi, i just quits after it loads all the file and the install button is clicked.
But it fully works when opened the .deb file from Files with root privileges.
How can I make I make it also work in the user Files.
thnks!

Comment: Try with Eddy instead - recommended on eOS over gdebi when installing .deb packages.

Comment: thanks! didn't know that one, i'll try it out.